# Accessing base class Resources in a WPF Page class

Tags: wpf, resources

I've got a custom WPF `Application` base class which has a set of resources specified in XAML in the `Application.Resources` property. I've changed the build action to `Page` from `ApplicationDefinition`.

Now I have another project, and I changed the App class to inherit from my custom application base above. However, I can't find how to access the resources which were specified in the base class's XAML file.

How can I load and access those resources, merging it with my derived `Application` classes `Resources`?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might be able to do is to use a merged dictionary. Its not exactly "inherited" but it works. I would separate out your resources into a shared xaml dictionary file, and then reference it from both your base Application, as well as your inheriting.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictonary Source="pack://application:,,,/ASSEMBLY;component/PATHTOSHAREDDICTIONARY"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <!-- More Resources can go here -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I'm not sure how this is going to play with your Application, but it might be worth a shot.  Good luck!

Note that ASSEMBLY and PATHTORESOURCEDICTIONARY will need to be replaced in your pack syntax.

Comment: This is what I'm using now, but I'd rather just inherit from the base class... I'm baffled as to why the resources are not loading.